# xelatex-biber in Sublime Text 3

Tags: installing, biber, sublime-text

I am new to LaTeX, using MacTeX 2014, biblatex 2.9/Biber 0.9. In need to create a custom build that includes xelatex-biber-xelatex in Sublime Text 3.

Comments below from @cfr and @egreg helped me to compile in terminal

Also @AndrewCashner helped me use Preview via terminal. No sync-jump between apps.

Comment: Try `/usr/texbin/biber` instead of `/usr/texbin/biber.exe`. You are not using Windows. It is very unlikely that MacTeX provides a `.exe` binary or that OS X could use it if it did. The error you get on the command line probably has a different cause but we need a [minimal (non-)working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for that.

Comment: So that file is `v.tex` and when you run `biber v` at the command line, you get the error you posted? Are you running `biber` from the directory which contains `v.tex`? That is, you change to that directory and then you run `pdflatex v.tex` then `biber v` and then `pdflatex v.tex`? If not, try that.

Comment: `biber v` tells `biber` to create the bibliography using the file `v.bcf`. The error you posted shows that `biber` is installed but that it cannot find `v.bcf`. Try running `biber` for the test document you posted after compiling it first with `pdflatex` (or `latex`) from the command line. If `biber` were not installed correctly, it would not be able to give you error messages. To get the version of `biber` run `biber --version` or `biber -v`. Note the `-` before the `v` which tells the command that this is a flag/option rather than the name of a file.

Comment: You have to run `pdflatex` or `latex` or `xelatex` first. If the file you posted is `test.tex`, you'd run `pdflatex test.tex` and then `biber test`. Just 'it doesn't work' isn't very informative. What error do you get? What does the log say? Is the initial compilation with `pdflatex` or whatever successful? `biber` is installed OK and the code looks fine so you need to tell us more if it is not working.

Comment: Yes. Terminal is the built-in way to access the command line. Not all editors have access to the command line. I don't know TexMate or Sublime Text. Kile has it. TeXShop does not (or did not). `cd` is the command to change directory. Normally, when you open a new session, you are in your home directory, `/Users/<your username>`. If your `.tex` file is in <your home directory> > Documents > MyProject, say, `cd Documents/MyProject` would change into the appropriate directory. Or `cd /Users/<your username>/Documents/MyProject` or `cd ~/Documents/MyProject`. (`~` is an abbreviation for your home.

Comment: @Nhaps What frontend are you using? TeXStudio, Texmaker on another one? It looks like the tool is misconfigured to add the `.tex` extension.

Comment: @Nhaps You shouldn't get the error if you call Biber from the terminal by `biber filename` or `biber filename.bcf`

Comment: That is a very different case, though. That means `biber` is at least trying to process the file, even if errors elsewhere prevent it producing a usable bibliography. Besides, why aren't you using the minimal test file you posted for this? The whole point is to avoid complications by using the simplest test case possible. You should stick to that test case until you get the basic problem sorted out. Only then should you introduce complications!

Comment: @egreg and especially cfr, thank you, thank you. Terminal is compiling biber (with warnings) and xelatex. This is a milestone, but I still need Sublime Text to do the same, please continue helping. If you can't, we can use TexMaker.

Comment: @cfr, you're right. But when I finally was able to output biber on the example I jumped right to my main work and yes, both are working. Sorry I forgot to tell you the first time. The editors, however, are stuck because of my lack of knowledge in setting up the right compiling specs: xelatex, biber, xelatex. Sublime is my main editor

Comment: I'm not clear what doesn't work exactly. Does XeLaTeX alone work? Did you make sure to change `biber.exe` to `biber`? What error do you get now? Note that we have no idea how you have configured Sublime and although you posted a partial screenshot of TeXMaker's config, that has been removed from the current version of your post.

Comment: Let me recap. Compiling began to work in mac terminal by excluding the extension of the file. This includes biber and pdflatex, and also xelatex. Now the good news is that TexMaker is also compiling correctly in xelatex including biber. Sublime Text is not yet. So we have made great progress here. And yes, I corrected the biber.exe to biber in TexMate

Comment: Do you mean in TeXMaker? Or are you also using TexMate? Have you checked your config in Sublime? I have never even seen Sublime so I have zero idea of anything unless you tell me. Perhaps @egreg is more familiar with it. (I've at least tried to use TeXMaker although it is not an editor I used for long. But I've zero experience with Sublime.) All I can tell you otherwise is: check the settings. Look for error messages. Is there a log file? Can you compile at all in Sublime or is only `biber` a problem?

Comment: I can compile with Sublime Text but only with standard builds they offer. I don't know how to set it up with xelatex-biber

Comment: Try setting it to `"/usr/texbin/biber" %.bcf`. Otherwise, I'm out of ideas. I guess check in terminal that `which biber` returns that path but since you are successfully using it for the other binaries, I can't imagine it won't be.

Comment: If you keep the PDF open in Preview, when you recompile in the Terminal, Preview will update the PDF to the new file.

Comment: @andrew, it updates ok but it requires   a mouse click in any portion of the preview. Should I expect Preview to update without this step?

Comment: @Nhaps - It's been a while since I did this on a Mac, so I'm not sure. You could also use a lightweight pdf viewer like `mupdf` (available from Macports) in a workflow like this: (1) edit and save .tex file in editor of choice, (2) compile in terminal (e.g., `xelatex file` then `biber file` then `xelatex file`); (3) do quick pdf preview (`mupdf file.pdf`). To close the mupdf window, just press `q`. You can keep the editor on one side and the terminal on the other side of the screen. This sort of thing has worked well for me (using `vim` and `tmux` for multiple terminal panes).

Comment: @Nhaps, you might know this, but typing the up arrow in the terminal will give you access to previously entered commands. So this makes repeated compilation cycles very easy.

Comment: @AndrewCashner, I'll be darned, I didn't know the arrows could help me this way, thanks. Let me know whether mudpf updates changes without the need to select, or click it, though this is not critical, but a convenience.

Comment: Updating is solved, but how to make syncing work? This is the whole point of the compiling build in Sublime Text.

Comment: @Nhaps The dedicated TeX editors like TeXShop do have a one-button solution like I think you want; otherwise it's just some variant of the cycle I described: edit, compile/recompile, preview, repeat. If you use keystrokes to navigate between windows you can do this all very quickly. Also some short Bash scripts and tricks like typing `!!` to repeat the last command help.

Comment: Good tips, I don't know yet how bash scripts and tricks like !! work. I can get by from what I learned in this thread. If I get an answer I will post it.

Answer (score 2):

1. To compile `xelatex`, `biber`, `xelatex` in Sublime Text 3 on a per document basis: Select Tools, Build System, LaTeX (I am using LaTeXing for ST). Now  add this to the top of your main tex file.

   ```
   %-*- program: xelatex -*-        
   %-*- program: biber -*-`        
   %-*- program: xelatex -*-
   ```

   Use Cmd+B to invoke compiling.
2. To see the results in Skim, go to Preferences, Sync, choose Preset: Custom. Under Command paste this:

   ```
   /Applications/Sublime Text 3.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl
   ```

   You may have to edit app name, as for most cases it's just `Sublime Text.app`

   And also for the Argument: `"%file":%line`

That's it. Now to jump from Skim to ST3: `cmd-shif-click` on any part of the PDF. From ST3 to Skim: `Command+l, j`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather post this is a comment than an answer since it doesn't reference Sublime Text 3, but I don't have the reputation for commenting. Anyway, at least in [Texpad](https://www.texpadapp.com/) on Mac creating a custom build script is very easy. You only need to make a .tpbuild script (which is just a BASH script);

```
#!/bin/bash

# run a .Rnw file through knitr first
# R -e 'library(knitr); knit("'$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT'.Rnw")'

# build a .tex file
xelatex -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT.tex"
biber "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT"
xelatex -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT.tex"
xelatex -synctex=1 "$TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT.tex"
```

Or whatever you like.

Comment: You have more reputation than I do, and I comment freely without any problem. I will keep note of this, but I don't think it will work for ST3.

Comment: No, this is a Texpad specific solution unfortunately (e.g. that variable $TEXPAD_ROOTFILE_NO_EXT if defined by Texpad). It's an alternative if Sublime Text won't play nicely though.

Comment: I can comment on my own answers, but not on others "[You must have 50 reputation or more to comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)".